# RLE an array of Text cells in Excel

Tags: excel, vba, encoding, run-length-encoding

I have an Excel file that contains output from another program.
It has the format of:

[image: Section of a larger array of values]

I would like to RLE encode this with a VBA Macro into a format similar to:

[image: First 3 lines RLE encoded.]

eg:
0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00  would be encoded as
4,0xff,4,0x00
represented as one cell with the Number of occurrences of the first character, 0xff until a change of value in the row, then a new count is started with the next characters number of repeats.

Is there a way to do this more simply that I am just not seeing?

Comment: Please edit the question, add the code you have tried, and specify the exact issue you encountered. The question as is at the moment is offtopic on SO.

Comment: "Is there a way to do this more simply ..." more simply *than what*? Without knowing what your current approach to writing this macro is, it is hard to say if there is a simpler way to do so.

Comment: Also, your description isn't clear. Are you run length encoding each row separately, or can a run span from one row to the next?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another simple approach. This will place encoded values 3 rows below the data as shown in the image.
[image]

May modify code to your requirement to place output in another sheet /Workbook.

```
Sub test()
Dim Rw As Long, Col As Long, Trw As Long, Tcol As Long, PrvVal As Variant, Val As Variant, Cnt As Long
Rw = 1
Trw = ActiveSheet.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 3  'Target row modify according to
'Trw = 20

With ActiveSheet
PrvVal = .Cells(Rw, 1).Value

Do While PrvVal <> ""
    Col = 1
    Tcol = 1
    Cnt = 0

    Do
    Val = .Cells(Rw, Col).Value
        If Val = PrvVal Then
        Cnt = Cnt + 1
        Else
        .Cells(Trw, Tcol).Value = Cnt & " " & PrvVal
        PrvVal = Val
        Cnt = 1
        Tcol = Tcol + 1
            If Val = "" Then
            Cnt = 0
            Exit Do
            End If
        End If
    Col = Col + 1
    Loop

Rw = Rw + 1
Trw = Trw + 1
PrvVal = .Cells(Rw, 1).Value
Loop
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you, this gives me plenty to work with to get this routine finished.  VBA is not a language I am comfortable using.  Typically I am just the hardware guy, but needed to get some data packed down quickly for a new design.  When I have gotten a complete solution for my needs, I will updated with my full script as used.

Comment: @R.Greenway Welcome any further queries regarding implementation  of the code (if lies within  my scope).

Answer (score 0):

This might give you some ideas:

```
Function RLE(items As Variant) As Collection
    'Takes a 1-dimensional array of items and returns a collection
    'which consists of alternating counts and items

    Dim item As Variant, count As Long
    Dim i As Long
    Dim Col As New Collection

    item = items(LBound(items))
    count = 1
    For i = LBound(items) + 1 To UBound(items)
        If items(i) = item Then
            count = count + 1
        Else
            Col.Add count
            Col.Add item
            item = items(i)
            count = 1
        End If
    Next i
    Col.Add count
    Col.Add item
    Set RLE = Col
End Function

'for testing purposes:

Function JoinCollection(C As Collection, Optional delim As String = "") As String
    Dim A As Variant
    Dim i As Long, n As Long

    n = C.count
    ReDim A(1 To n)
    For i = 1 To n
        A(i) = C(i)
    Next i
    JoinCollection = Join(A, delim)
End Function
```

For example, in the Immediate Window:

```
?JoinCollection(RLE(Array("H","T","T","T","H","H","T","H","H","H","T")))
1H3T2H1T3H1T
```

Comment: Thanks John.  I see how this is working now.   I believe that I have enough to work with to complete my need.